# ioslides background with css, title slide

Tags: html, css, r-markdown, ioslides

When I have a slide mid-presentation that has a big title on it the background color is grey, but I want it to be white.  What CSS code can I add to do this? I already figured out how to make all my text black, but how do I make that slide a white background?

For example:

```
---
title: "Untitled"
output: ioslides_presentation
---



## R Markdown

This is an R Markdown presentation.


# Make this slide white background (black text)

## Slide with Bullets

- Bullet 1
- Bullet 2
- Bullet 3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Slides, those have level1 header, but not the title-slide has the class `dark` specified. So overwriting the `background` property for the class `dark` changes that grey background.

```
---
title: "Untitled"
output: ioslides_presentation
css: style.css
---

## R Markdown

This is an R Markdown presentation.


# Make this slide white background (black text)

## Slide with Bullets

- Bullet 1
- Bullet 2
- Bullet 3
```

**style.css**

```
slides > slide.dark {
  background: white !important;
}

slide.dark h2 {
  color: black !important;
}
```

---

[image: slide with bg]

---